# AWS CloudFormation configuration S3 event to sqs

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless

I'm trying to create a simple AWS based architecture that would transfer some data from a AWS S3 to SQS and then that would trigger a lambda. I'm using Serverless framework but eventually when I deploy I get this error

**An error occurred: PostsRawBucket - Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID:...; S3 Extended Request ID:...)**

```
# CloudFormation
resources:
  Resources:
    PostsTransferQueue:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
      Properties:
        VisibilityTimeout: 180
        MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
        QueueName: posts-transfer
    PostsRawBucket:
      Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
      DependsOn:
        - PostsTransferQueue
      Properties:
        BucketName: posts-raw
        NotificationConfiguration:
          QueueConfigurations:
            - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
              Queue: !GetAtt PostsTransferQueue.Arn
```

**Edit 1: The solution (at least for me) - I had to add AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy**

```
QueuePolicy:
      Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
      DependsOn:
        - PostsTransferQueue
      Properties:
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                AWS: '*'
              Action:
                - SQS:SendMessage
              # Target a wildcard resource name based on the same format as QueueName
              Resource: !Join [ "", [ "arn:aws:sqs:*:*:", !Join [ "-", [ posts, transfer ] ], "*" ] ]
              Condition:
                ArnLike:
                  # Static BucketName used to avoid circular dependency with S3 bucket
                  aws:SourceArn: !Join [ "", ["arn:aws:s3:*:*:", !Join [ "-", [ posts, raw, v2] ] ] ]
        Queues:
          - !Ref PostsTransferQueue
```

An then you have to update S3 to depend on the **QueuePolicy** too

```
PostsRawBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      DependsOn:
        - PostsTransferQueue
        - QueuePolicy
      ...
```

Also I changed the names of the S3 bucket and the Queue to

`BucketName: !Join [ "-", [ posts, raw, v2] ]`

`QueueName: !Join [ "-", [ posts, transfer, v2] ]`

Comment: Your CloudFormation looks correct. You could try and comment out parts of it and try deploy to see which line(s) should be relevant cause of the error. Or we might be able to help you get around it some other way if you describe your use case a bit more. I do something similar with AWS-Lambda, SQS and S3 combination but I did not use NotificationConfiguration or QueueConfigurations at all, so maybe you can do without them too...

Comment: So basically I'm trying to put some jsons in S3 bucket and then i wan't to link the S3 to SQS which would trigger a lambda that would do certain job. [S3 -> SQS -> Lambda]. The problem is in the S3 Bucket -> Properties -> NotificationConfiguration -> QueueConfiguration -> ... And when i comment this part its working correctly (without linking them)

Comment: But would it work to let the Lambda listen to the S3 bucket directly? Why not? Then you will not need the queue in between, you just let the Lambda listen for `event: s3:ObjectCreated:*`

Comment: Yes but i need the queue to store the metadata for up to 14 days and to work as a fall back mechanism (For example if for some reason the lambda fails somehow it it won't delete the item from the queue and eventually another lambda would try to process the data)

BTW i found the solution I had to add AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy